# Not getting designed layout

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

[Vuetify official example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/examples/layouts/centered)

I have, say copied the layout from the vuetify docs but I am not getting the same layout. I cannot figure out what is blocking me. Is there some default properties that I have to deal with?

**Login.vue:**

```html
    <template>
    <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-content>
      <v-container
        class="fill-height"
        fluid
      >
        <v-row 
          align="center"
          justify="center"
        >
          <v-col
            cols="12"
            sm="8"
            md="4"
          >
            <v-card class="elevation-12">
              <v-toolbar
                color="primary"
                dark
                flat
              >
                <v-toolbar-title>Login</v-toolbar-title>
                <v-spacer />

              </v-toolbar>
              <v-card-text>
                <v-form>
                  <v-text-field
                    label="Login"
                    name="login"
                    prepend-icon="person"
                    type="text"
                    v-model="username"
                  />

                  <v-text-field
                    id="password"
                    label="Password"
                    name="password"
                    prepend-icon="lock"
                    type="password"
                    v-model="password"
                  />
                </v-form>
              </v-card-text>
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer />
                <v-btn @click="login" color="primary" >Login</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
      </v-content>
     </v-app>
    </template>
```

**app.vue:**

```html
    <template>
    <v-app id="app">
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid>
        <router-view />
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
    </v-app>
    </template>
    <script>
```

I do not have any custom designed css. I am using `vue-cli`.

Here is what my layout looks like:

[image]

With no error in console.
[image]

Comment: does pressing `F12, Ctrl+Shift+M` in the browser do anything? It seems to [work](https://codepen.io/depperm/pen/MWYQagb?&editable=true&editors=101)

Comment: @depperm Thank you for your response. I have added the update on `F12` view.